# Card Fragment in Android wear does not appear on bottom of screen

Tags: android, wear-os

Hi 
 I am working on android wearable application , in which I was using card frame where I used the sample example given in "http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html#card-fragment" .
The cardFragment does not appear at the bottom of the screen,instead it appears on the top of the screen.Is it the desired behavior or is it issue with SDK. I checked in both Emulator and Moto 360 2nd generation. In both cases the CardFragment appears at the top rather than bottom.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

The below XML is used:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/robot_background"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="bottom">

        <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/custom_card"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `layout_gravity:"bottom"` to your CardFrame :

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
```